# Fill color in div from bottom using css

Tags: css

I want to fill color in div from bottom using css. My requirement is that I have one semi transparent image, I have put this image in div. I want to fill color in that div from bottom instead of top. I have tried below code for apply this effect but did not succeeded so please see my code and tell me what is the mistake. I write inline css in div. I have increase height of image container div using chrome inspect element.

```
<div style="width:128px;height:128px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
 <div style="width:100%;height:0%;bottom:0;background-color:green;">
  <img src="images/test.png" class="footprint_img"/>
     <div>test</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div's height is zero. So it will not show up. Besides, you may fill div with transparent color using `linear-gradient` property of CSS3.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <div>test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS would be like the following: You may easily get CSS code from colorzilla.com/gradient-editor

```
.outerDiv {
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.innerDiv {
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzk0ZDg2MyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUiLz4KICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzk0ZDg2MyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUiLz4KICA8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PgogIDxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZC11Y2dnLWdlbmVyYXRlZCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 0%, rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 0%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 0%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 0%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 0%,rgba(148,216,99,0.5) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8094d863', endColorstr='#8094d863',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    /* IE6-8 */
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Fiddle is here

Answer (score -1):

Remove YOur inner **div** `height width bottom`

```
<div style="width:128px;height:128px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
 <div style="background-color:green;">
  <img src="images/test.png" class="footprint_img"/>
     <div>test</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2HpHU/1/)**

==========================

**Don't used inline css used to this way**

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
  <img src="images/test.png" class="footprint_img"/>
     <div>test</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.parent{
    width:128px;
    height:128px;overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.child{background-color:green;}
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/2HpHU/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have already made css file for it but I want to inline css temporary for testing.

Comment: I have already write in my question I want to fill color from bottom not set background color directly. because I want to apply effect like fill color in semi transparent image.